# ObservableCollection: how to use the FirstOrDefault?

Tags: observablecollection

I have a custom class, with a property ID. We can name this class A, and the property ID.

I have an observable collection of A, and I would like to get the firstOrDefault to know if an object exists with a determined ID. Soy I do the following:

myObersableCollection.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ID==2)

But I get the following error: it is not possible to convert implicitly A into bool.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` returns a matching object, not a boolean.

If you just want to check whether there is a matching object, call `.Any()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It's true. I was trying to simplify code using the FirstOrDefault in condition of my if.